# Combining futures and exceptions

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand how futures can be combined with exceptions. The function FutureA either returns a future or it throws an exception. When I try to catch the exception nothing happens. Why is that?

```
package test

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


object TestFutures extends App {

  def futureA(x: Int) = Future { 
    if (x==1)
      1
    else
        throw new Exception("there's an error")
  }

   try {
       futureA(2)
   }
   catch {
     case ex:Exception => println("an exception was thrown")     

   }

   println("end")
   Thread.sleep(15000)
}
```

Comment: To be precise, your description of the function FutureA is inaccurate.  The function returns a future, and that future represents either a value or an exception.  An exception raised in the body of the future won't be seen by the caller because that code may not have even started executing when FutureA returns.

Comment: isn't that the reason you need to use `recover` to catch the exception?

Comment: Again, being very careful about the wording: `recover` doesn't catch the exception, `Future.apply` catches the exception.  `recover` says what the value of the Future will be if a matching exception was caught by `Future.apply`.

Comment: (Missed my edit window to add to the above comment).  Technically, the exception isn't being caught by `Future.apply`, either (again, because the body may not have been executed yet when it returns).  The actual catching of the exception would be somewhere in the `ExecutionContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you catch exceptions that can be thrown by functions that return futures:

```
package test

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


object TestFutures extends App {

  def futureA(x: Int) = Future { 
    if (x==1)
      1
    else
        throw new Exception("there's an error")
  }

    futureA(2).map { result =>
         println("OK")
    }
    .recover{ 
        case ex:Exception => println("an exception was thrown")     
     }

   println("end")
   Thread.sleep(15000)
}
```